# Pandas to SQLite - Incorrect data type

Tags: python, pandas, database, sqlite, etl

I've created a string in Python to read a csv and, after, write the dataframe in sqlite3.
I've got troubles with amount fields.
I give you an example:

1. In the csv the field I read is lije this ";          17.488,85;";
2. In pandas I use a "str.replace" instruction to delete the spaces before the number;
3. When I write to sqlite the column is defined as "real" and the visual result is like this[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqz9Q.png).

If I perform a sum in sql the amount which is exposed as result is [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZxTx.png).

Can anyone help me to handle this issue?

Thanks a lot

Enrico

Comment: Please post text-based values as text rather than images, and post the snippet of code you're having trouble with (in this case, probably the code line you're using to perform the sum). Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The first image shows the `.` and `,` backwards to my US eyes. That could be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're dealing with an European csv (semicolon as a separator for the values), you need to pass the parameter `thousands` to [**`pandas.read_csv`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html).

Try this :

```
pd.read_csv('your_csv_file.csv', thousands=r',', sep=';')
```